# Linux Shared Memory with C++: Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, ipc, shared-memory

I'm following the Linux Programming Interface book (page 1004-1005).

I know the book uses C. But I'd like to implement the same behavior in C++. That is: share a struct between processes through shared memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

using namespace std;

struct my_pair {
  int a;
  int b;
};

int main()
{
  key_t key = ftok("aaaaa", 1);
  int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(my_pair), IPC_CREAT);
  my_pair *numbers;
  numbers = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

  cout << numbers->a;

  return 0;
}
```

It gives me this error:

> shteste.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> shteste.cpp:18: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'my_pair*'

I understand that C++ is more strict. If I cast the return of shmat to (my_pair *), it compiles but gives me segmentation fault during execution.

Is it possible (how) to use Linux / C shared memory facilities with C++ ?

I'm compiling with: G++ 4.4.7: g++ shteste.cpp -o shteste -std=c++0x

Thanks...

**EDIT: Following all sugestions, this is the code now:**

```
int main()
{
 key_t key;

 if ((key = ftok("/home/alunos/scd/g11/aaaaa", 1)) == (key_t) -1) {
   perror("IPC error: ftok"); exit(1);
 }

 int shmid = shmget(key , sizeof(my_pair), IPC_CREAT | 0640);

 if (shmid == -1) {
     perror("Could not get shared memory");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }

 my_pair *numbers;
 void* mem = (my_pair*) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
 if (mem == reinterpret_cast<void*>(-1)) {
     perror("Could not get shared memory location");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 } else {
     numbers = reinterpret_cast<my_pair*>(mem);
     cout << numbers->a;
 }

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

aaaaa contents: notacat

> [scd11@VM11 ~]$ ./shteste
>
> Could not get shared memory: Permission denied

Comment: Are you sure the error is produced by the code you show? I would expect this error if you didn't have the cast, as in `numbers = shmat(...)`. But the cast should take care of it.

Comment: You are correct... I copied the "fixed"code... the one which I cast (and, thus, don`t complain about conversion) but get segmentation fault.

Comment: You should check return value from `shmget` and `shmat`.

Comment: If I test your code with strace, I got:  "64 5327  shmget(0xffffffff, 8, IPC_CREAT|000) = 11534358
 65 5327  shmat(11534358, NULL, 0)          = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: C allows casting other pointer types to/from `void*` implicitly, C++ requires you to cast it.

Comment: Does a file named `aaaaa` actually exist? `ftok` requires an existing, accessible file. My guess is, it (or some other API call) fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a permissions issue. You can check the return values of `shmget` and `shmat` and use `perror` to print a human-readable error message like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct my_pair {
  int a;
  int b;
};

int main()
{
  key_t key = ftok("aaaaa", 1);
  int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(my_pair), IPC_CREAT | 0777);
  if (shmid == -1) {
      perror("Could not get shared memory");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  my_pair *numbers;
  void* mem = (my_pair*) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
  if (mem == reinterpret_cast<void*>(-1)) {
      perror("Could not get shared memory location");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  } else {
      numbers = reinterpret_cast<my_pair*>(mem);
      cout << numbers->a;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct: "Could not get shared memory location: Permission denied". Should I ask the system administrator or there is anything that I, as the user/developer, can do ?

Comment: @VictorMarconi: No, you should set the permissions correctly :-) See my answer!

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone. All answers helped... the problem was a bit of each.

The wrong permission. Therefore, I couldn`t use the same key again (ftok). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You simple forget to set the permissions:

```
int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(my_pair), IPC_CREAT | 0777);
```

As I already mentioned in my comment, the result of the failing command can be seen with strace.

```
64 5327 shmget(0xffffffff, 8, IPC_CREAT|000) = 11534358
65 5327 shmat(11534358, NULL, 0) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)"
```

If your file "aaaaa" is existing, the code works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a permissions issue.

Per [the `shmget()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html):

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <sys/shm.h>
>
> int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ...
>
> - The low-order nine bits of *shm_perm.mode* are set to the low-order    nine bits of *shmflg*.

You didn't set any permission bits.  The low-order nine bits of *shmflag* in your call are all zero:

```
int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(my_pair), IPC_CREAT);
```

You need to set the proper permissions, something like this:

```
int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(my_pair), IPC_CREAT|0640);
```

You will also likely have to use `ipcrm` to remove the current shared-memory segment, as it will remain as-is with the incorrect permssions. Even if you change your code, your `shmget()` calls will return the id of the existing segment - the one that you can't attach because the permissions are missing.

First, use `ipcs -a` to list the shared memory segments, then use `ipcrm -m shmid` or `ipcrm -M shmkey` to remove the segment with incorrect permissions.

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone. All answers helped... the problem was a bit of each.

The wrong permission. Therefore, I couldn`t use the same key again (ftok). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`ftok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftok.3.html) man page:

```
The ftok() function uses the identity of the file named by the given
pathname (which must refer to an existing, accessible file).
```

With existing file your code will work.

Alternatively you can use:

```
key = IPC_PRIVATE
```

which will be sufficient for this example, but will not work for real IPC.

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone. All answers helped... the problem was a bit of each.

The wrong permission. Therefore, I couldn`t use the same key again (ftok). Thanks a lot.