# Cannot manipulate the array of struct cause segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Hi i have the user that get randomly a number, make a structure called transaction and add it to a list. The problem is that give me back segmentation fault but i don't know where is the problem.
This is a big problem cause this program is launched by another like his son, if the segmentation will not be solved the father cannot do his duty.

main:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    id = atoi(argv[1]);
    int shmid = shmget(SH_KEY, SO_NODES_NUM * sizeof(pid_t), IPC_EXCL | 0666);
    int *nodeList = (int *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    initTransactionPool();
    struct Transaction prova1;

    while (1)
    {
        int r1 = rand() % totalBudget + 2;
        /*getBudget();
        setBudget();*/
        if (totalBudget<2)
        {
            break;
        }
        
        prova1.money = r1;
        prova1.receiver = 12;
        prova1.sender = 1;
        prova1.reward = 1;
        prova1.timestamp = "ciao";
        addTransaction(prova1);
        totalBudget-=r1;
        printf("\n il budget e' %d",totalBudget);
    }
    freeTransactionPool();
    return 0;
}
```

other function:

```
void initTransactionPool()
{
    transactionPool = (struct Transaction *)malloc(SO_TP_SIZE * sizeof(struct Transaction *));
}

void freeTransactionPool()
{
    free(transactionPool);
}

int addTransaction(struct Transaction transaction)
{
    if (sizePool >= SO_TP_SIZE - 1)
        return -1;
    ++sizePool;
    transactionPool[sizePool] = transaction;
    return 0;
}
```

the data:  `transactionPool`

is saved in a ".h" like this : `extern struct Transaction* transactionPool;`

and in a ":c" like this: `struct Transaction* transactionPool;`

Comment: `transactionPool = (struct Transaction *)malloc(SO_TP_SIZE * sizeof(struct Transaction *));` this smells because it looks like you are allocating only space for a pointer instead of the structure. Also note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: I removed the cast but the segmentation fault persit

Comment: transactionPool is a pointer like this saved in a labrary "user_manager.h" : struct Transaction *transactionPool;

Comment: It's not about the cast but about the size. You need `sizeof(struct Transaction)`, not a pointer

Answer (score 1):

> *"I removed the cast but the segmentation fault persit "*

The seg fault is not being caused by the cast, it is occurring because in this call:

```
void initTransactionPool()
{
    transactionPool = (struct Transaction *)malloc(SO_TP_SIZE * sizeof(struct Transaction *));
}
```

`transactionPool` is allocated only the number of bytes that matches the size of a pointer on your system. (typically 4 on 32bit system or 8 for 64bit system)  So, if an attempt is made to write anything to this allocated area of memory that is larger than `4` (or `8`) `bytes`, it will optimally result in a `seg-fault`, clearly indicating to you that there is a problem in the code. Alternatively it could *appear* to do nothing, while in reality your code is brushing up against [undefined behavior](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). (where anything can happen, even nothing for awhile, then for no apparent reason crash.)

Change it to:

```
struct Transaction* initTransactionPool(void)
{
    transactionPool = malloc(SO_TP_SIZE * sizeof(struct Transaction));
    return transactionPool ;//caller must check for NULL before using 
}
```

or

```
struct Transaction* initTransactionPool(void)
{
    transactionPool = malloc(SO_TP_SIZE * sizeof(*transactionPool));
    return transactionPool;//caller must check for NULL before using 
}
```

Note, added the return to allow caller to check for `NULL` upon return, eg:

```
//in calling function:
if(!initTransactionPool())
{
    //handle error
}
//continue.
```

About the cast...
It is removed here because although it is required if using `C++`, it is considered [bad practice in `C`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Having the cast when using `C` is not a guaranteed problem, but can be for the reasons cited in the link.

There are other problems with this code as well, including the function `addTransaction`.  If you get stuck with those, post another question with a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did the changes but still get segmenation fault when i start it. Even do i put a printf in the start of the code exit with segmentation fault and doesn't print anything

Comment: @MatteoPagliarello -  Have you run your program in debug, with break points in the spots where you suspect the problem occurs?   Stepping through the code one line at a time will likely show you where exactly in your code the problem occurs, and from there the reason for the problem can likely be determined.  (for example [debugging in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)).

Comment: @MatteoPagliarello - I would suggest temporarily removing user input and hard code the value at top of main function.  ( i.e. `id = 10;` )  Then also temporarily remove `shm...()` functions.  If the seg-fault goes away, [then they are the culprit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46505572/645128).  What are your permissions?

Comment: I tried to run debug but it says that failed at start and exit with value -1

Comment: Oh yes maybe the atoi could be a problem

Comment: Maybe was atoi, cause argv[1] is filled by a process father. But when i launch only the child to test obv it gave me seg. fault.

Comment: But now give me back floating point exeception :(

Comment: @MatteoPagliarello -  You've got some weird stuff going on.   Get rid of `argv[1]` and hard code the value, as I suggested before, and the rest too.   If I was on Linux I might be able to help further.  But I am not.   Good luck, sorry I could not help further.  Have you considered `shmget()` may have a bad argument, and it is the cause.  Or that your permissions are not high enough to call?  (See my earlier link _then they are the culprit_.)